# Socat gets hanged

Tags: socat

As a part of proxy forwarding, we have socat and we have stash on other server
The socat process is getting hanged frequently and users are effected. Since the socat gets hanged users will not be able to clone the repository using ssh link for clone.
As a temporary solution for this we are restarting socat when the users report the issue.

We are unable to find the root cause for this. If there are any known solutions for this issue please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest increasing the information being logged by using multiple `-d` options upon restarting socat. Have that be dumped into a local file and when it hangs on you again, you'll be able to provide us with something to go on (or might even figure it out for yourself).